# AD Authentication fails in local machine but works from Production server

Tags: active-directory, authentication

Hi, I am using AD authentication and facing 2 problems.

1. Authentication works fine when I move the application to a production server but FAILS in my LOCAL machine.

Both local machine and server are in same domain and used the same domain account logging in.

2. When the machine logs in the users with their domain account, AD authentication from the application says that the account is not valid.

Please give me any suggestions for the problem and/or solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the following things :

1. error in AD event log (this will give you an idea if there are any errors from protocol host authentication , if the request reaches the AD)
2. That no firewall is blocking the requests (Strict antivirus software can block requests too.)
3. event log from your local machine
4. Depending on what authentication the application uses you might want to check

   1. LDAP (steps 1-2) + if it's inhouse built aplication put a log in the authentication part
   2. Kerberos - tickets and logs from AD
   3. NTLM - step 1-2

If by any chance you are the domain admin , you could try to take the local machine outside of the domain then AD it again .

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure both machines using the same DNS servers as the AD server.